# Prevent scrolling on a listview (once tapped)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile-listview, iscrollview

JQ 1.9.1, JQM 1.3.1, iscrollview 1.3.1

I have a list of items in a listview. Clicking on one li sends a JSON request and opens a description page.

Since the opening of the description page takes 1 or 2 seconds there is time to continue scrolling on the listview which messes up the bottom bar when the transition happens.

How can I simply stop any scrolling up and down of the list once I've received a click event ?  Something like :

```
  <div data-role='content' data-iscroll>
    <ul id='mylist'></ul>
  </div>


$('#mylist').click(function(e){ STOP ANY listview scrolling }
```